# How can I tell which model a disk drive is from Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I looked in the device manager, but it shows a generic model.

I also have no access to the physical machine itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have no physical access, I'm guessing this is a server? If it's got a proper RAID controller, you can't see the actual disks from inside the OS. Apart from using RAID management tools, there isn't any way around this, unless you've got light-out management.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a program like SIW to see if it can tell what make/model it is.

http://www.gtopala.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try double-clicking on the disk drive in device manager to open the drive properties.  Then, go to the "Details" tab and select the "Hardware Ids" property from the "Property" dropdown.

Often, there are values in that property that give you the drive model or there are some hex values that you can do an internet search for to get the drive model.